# Event brite API does not display my event

Tags: php, api, eventbrite

I'm trying to display my events from eventbrite using their API. I made an event that is public but when I use this api call in php, I am not getting my event. I see other peoples event that's from CAnada and in July. Here's my code

```
$json_url ="https://www.eventbrite.com/json/event_search?app_key=".$authentication_tokens['app_key']."&date=Next+month&country=CA";
        $response = file_get_contents($json_url);
        $list_events = json_decode($response, true);
        var_dump($list_events);
```

ANyone know why my event is not in the $list_events?

Answer (score 0):

You are making a request to the search API for any Canadian event next month.  By default search results are limited to 100 results:

http://developer.eventbrite.com/doc/events/event_search/

As you can imagine, there are probably way more than 100 events in Canada that start next month.  Provided your event is "public" it will be searchable (if you can find it on the website, that's good).  If you continue to page through the results you will eventually find it.

If you're simply looking to retrieve your event via the API, [event_get](http://developer.eventbrite.com/doc/events/event_get/) is the call you'll want to use.  If you want a listing of only your events, use [user_list_events](http://developer.eventbrite.com/doc/events/user_list_events/).